# Suggestion needed for display previews on website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project, my page have lots of images(like 100, they are all dynamic contents), I want each them to show a preview block with image, date and time, text, title inside of the block when mouse hover.

**Wonder which way is the best way to do this.**

1. create a hidden div block with everything in it, use jquery to show and hide it.
2. use jquery to append it and then remove it.
3. your method.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `1`, but this is the wrong site to ask this. The following is better for your question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you going to be loading all 100 images on the first load or is it like you'll be getting blocks of images maybe 20 at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think The most effective way to do that is to load first just the preview Things, and When you need, get Specific content with AJAX.

Comment: I like this approach myself. The idea of showing the preview and when you click on it maybe you get a larger image that has the associated meta data loaded via ajax. Similar to how facebook currently loads comments on the right side of a picture once you click the thumbnail